# How can I fix an error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"

Tags: javascript, html

I am new in web developing, and actually I don't know almost nothing about js.

I am trying to "disable" 3 buttons and then they are clicked for 5 seconds. I have got the Id's right but it gives me this error only for the `stop` and `restart` button/i. It work fines for `play`.

```
Error that I got -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at actionButtonfuction (Website:145)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (Website:179)
```

Is there any limitation for how many items can be styled in single function?

```html
<script>
  function actionButtonfuction() {
    document.getElementById("actionButton").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("play").style.color = "#808080";
    document.getElementById("stop").style.color = "#808080";
    document.getElementById("restart").style.color = "#808080";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("actionButton").disabled = false;
      document.getElementById("play").style.color = "#16a72d";
      document.getElementById("stop").style.color = "#db3224";
      document.getElementById("restart").style.color = "#1b6ec2"
    }, 5000);
    //console.log("button clicked");
  }
</script>

<button class="console_button" onclick="actionButtonfuction()" id="actionButton" asp-action="">
  <i id="stop" class="fa fa-stop"></i>
</button>

<button class="console_button" onclick="actionButtonfuction()" id="actionButton" asp-action="">
   <i id="play" class="fa fa-play"></i>
</button>

<button class="console_button" onclick="actionButtonfuction()" id="actionButton" asp-action="">
   <i id="restart" class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: I do not see any issue here and to answer the question there is `NO` limit to do styling.

Comment: An id should refer to a unique element. Use a class if you need to have several elements sharing some behavior.

Comment: first of all, you should use the same id for different elements. notice that all 3 <button> has the same id="actionButton". you can try get the buttons by class name "console_button"

Comment: You do NOT have unique `id` which is big cause of this issue could become if you follow this practice. `id's` have to be unique to each elements. `class` can be similar

Comment: better add terminator `;` in last line, ` document.getElementById("restart").style.color = "#1b6ec2"`

Comment: @user4642212 Yeah I noticed late, but the problem still exists when there are 3 elements with `id="actionButton"`

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Please [edit] your question, provide clear steps to reproduce, provide a [mre], i.e. your _complete, minimal, and [valid](https://html5.validator.nu/)_ HTML document (with `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>`) that shows how exactly the `<script>` relates to the rest of your HTML.

Comment: @user3647971 There’s no error thrown on this line.

Comment: Only thing not working is the disabling and it's because you have all those buttons with same id, and getElementById returns first one found.

Comment: Guys I found another issue, because the site is auto generated by ASP.Net Core , one of the 3 buttons always isn't generated, depending on the situation, so that's why it never works. Thank you all for your help, I learned today something new!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple elements you should use a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class).  [id attributes must be unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) within a page and is designed as a unique id to reference one DOM object.  You also need to iterate over all the DOM objects you want to act on.

I have added actionButton to the class of each button, and used [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) to get all of them, and a [for-of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to iterate over them.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script>
  function actionButtonfuction() {
    for(const el of document.getElementsByClassName("actionButton"))
      el.disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("play").style.color = "#808080";
    document.getElementById("stop").style.color = "#808080";
    document.getElementById("restart").style.color = "#808080";
    setTimeout(function() {
      for(const el of document.getElementsByClassName("actionButton"))
        el.disabled = false;
      document.getElementById("play").style.color = "#16a72d";
      document.getElementById("stop").style.color = "#db3224";
      document.getElementById("restart").style.color = "#1b6ec2"
    }, 5000);
    //console.log("button clicked");
  }
</script>

<button class="console_button actionButton" onclick="actionButtonfuction()" asp-action="">
  <i id="stop" class="fa fa-stop"></i>
</button>

<button class="console_button actionButton" onclick="actionButtonfuction()" asp-action="">
   <i id="play" class="fa fa-play"></i>
</button>

<button class="console_button actionButton" onclick="actionButtonfuction()" asp-action="">
   <i id="restart" class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: I found another issue, because the site is auto generated by ASP.Net Core ,always one of the 3 buttons isn't generated, depending on the situation, so that's why it never works. Thank you for your help, I learned today something new!

Answer (score 1):

First, all your buttons have the same ID, which is not allowed because IDs are supposed to be unique.
Second, in your code there is nothing like an id of `play`, `stop` or `restart`.
I’m thinking that for your code to work, it should be like this:

```
<script>
    function actionButtonfuction() {
        var btns = document.getElementsByClassName('actionButton');
        for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
           btns[i].setAttribute('disabled','true');
        }
        document.getElementById("play").style.color = "#808080";
        document.getElementById("stop").style.color = "#808080";
        document.getElementById("restart").style.color = "#808080";
        setTimeout(() => {
            var btns = document.getElementsByClassName('actionButton');
            for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
               btns[i].setAttribute('disabled','true');
            }
            document.getElementById("play").style.color = "#16a72d";
            document.getElementById("stop").style.color = "#db3224";
            document.getElementById("restart").style.color = "#1b6ec2"
        }, 5000);
    }
</script>
```

For the HTML:

```
<button class="console_button" class="actionButton" onclick="actionButtonfuction()" id="stop" asp-action="">
   <i class="fa fa-stop"></i>
</button>

<button class="console_button" class="actionButton" onclick="actionButtonfuction()" id="play" asp-action="">
   <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
</button>

<button class="console_button" class="actionButton" onclick="actionButtonfuction()" id="restart" asp-action="">
   <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
</button>
```

So altogether like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Buttons</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <button class="console_button" class="actionButton" onclick="actionButtonfuction()" id="stop" asp-action="">
   <i class="fa fa-stop"></i>
</button>

<button class="console_button" class="actionButton" onclick="actionButtonfuction()" id="play" asp-action="">
   <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
</button>

<button class="console_button" class="actionButton" onclick="actionButtonfuction()" id="restart" asp-action="">
   <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
</button>
  <script>
    function actionButtonfuction() {
        var btns = document.getElementsByClassName('actionButton');
        for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
           btns[i].setAttribute('disabled','true');
        }
        document.getElementById("play").style.color = "#808080";
        document.getElementById("stop").style.color = "#808080";
        document.getElementById("restart").style.color = "#808080";
        setTimeout(() => {
            var btns = document.getElementsByClassName('actionButton');
            for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
               btns[i].setAttribute('disabled','false');
            }
            document.getElementById("play").style.color = "#16a72d";
            document.getElementById("stop").style.color = "#db3224";
            document.getElementById("restart").style.color = "#1b6ec2"
        }, 5000);
    }
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please do take note that I’ve not tested the code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the actual answer to my problem

```
<script>
function actionButtonfuction() {
    for (const el of document.getElementsByClassName("actionButton"))
        el.disabled = true;
    if (typeof (document.getElementById("play")) != 'undefined' && document.getElementById("play") != null) {
        document.getElementById("play").style.color = "#808080";
    } 
    if (typeof (document.getElementById("stop")) != 'undefined' && document.getElementById("stop") != null) {
        document.getElementById("stop").style.color = "#808080";
    }
    if (typeof (document.getElementById("restart")) != 'undefined' && document.getElementById("restart") != null) {
        document.getElementById("restart").style.color = "#808080";
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        for (const el of document.getElementsByClassName("actionButton"))
            el.disabled = false;
        if (typeof (document.getElementById("play")) != 'undefined' && document.getElementById("play") != null) {
            document.getElementById("play").style.color = "#16a72d";
        }
        if (typeof (document.getElementById("stop")) != 'undefined' && document.getElementById("stop") != null) {
            document.getElementById("stop").style.color = "#db3224";
        }
        if (typeof (document.getElementById("restart")) != 'undefined' && document.getElementById("restart") != null) {
            document.getElementById("restart").style.color = "#1b6ec2"
        }
    }, 5000);
    //console.log("button clicked");
}
```